Unable to Connect WebSocket with NestJS and Apache Reverse Proxy on HTTPS
I have an application built with NestJS deployed on an EC2 instance using Apache as the reverse proxy. The application is accessible via both HTTP and HTTPS. I have a WebSocket setup that works perfectly when accessed via the public EC2 URL (HTTP), but I encounter an error when trying to connect via the HTTPS domain.
Setup Details

Public EC2 URL (HTTP):

http://ec2-16-170-219-11.eu-north-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3011


Domain (HTTPS):

https://dev-ubreality-api.beyonditsolution.com



Apache Configuration
HTTP Configuration (/etc/httpd/conf.d/dev-ubreality-api.beyonditsolution.com.conf):
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev-ubreality-api.beyonditsolution.com

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3011/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3011/

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =dev-ubreality-api.beyonditsolution.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

HTTPS Configuration (/etc/httpd/conf.d/dev-ubreality-api.beyonditsolution.com.conf):
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName dev-ubreality-api.beyonditsolution.com

    Define APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/httpd

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3011/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3011/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev-ubreality-api.beyonditsolution.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev-ubreality-api.beyonditsolution.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev-ubreality-api.beyonditsolution.com/chain.pem

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dev-ubreality-api.beyonditsolution.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/dev-ubreality-api.beyonditsolution.com-access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} =Upgrade [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*) ws://localhost:3011/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*) http://localhost:3011/$1 [P,L]
</VirtualHost>

Error Details


When trying to connect to the WebSocket via the domain on HTTPS, I receive the following error:
Error: Unexpected server response: 400
Handshake Details
Request URL: https://dev-ubreality-api.beyonditsolution.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket
Request Method: GET
Request Headers
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: buavVbK8UlQQKmIOyAL1sw==
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
authentication: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImFkbWluQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTY5ODA3MjI1NCwiZXhwIjoxNjk4MTA4MjU0fQ.xgn8kjYuuFt1uA9QDBY0HbtAsW4GWR1XXdpkOXInX9I
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Host: dev-ubreality-api.beyonditsolution.com

Steps Taken

Verified Apache configuration syntax using sudo apachectl configtest.
Checked Apache error logs for any issues.
Ensured that the SSL certificates are correctly configured.

Observations

WebSocket connection works when using the public EC2 URL over HTTP.
WebSocket connection fails with a 400 error when using the HTTPS domain.

Additional Information

EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 2.
Apache version: 2.4.56
Web application built using NestJS and Socket.io.

Question
How can I configure Apache to correctly handle WebSocket connections over HTTPS? Are there any additional modules or configurations required to support WebSocket connections on an HTTPS reverse proxy?
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
I tried Chatgpt 4 o answers and changed apache configuration to tackle the issue but failed badly
